# Simple expect script

Tags: linux, ssh, expect

I'm trying to run a simple expect script that create a file in the remote host, here the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh numeutente@11.11.11.111
expect "password: "
send "psw\r"
expect "$ "
send "cd /var/www/localhost/htdocs/oss\r"
send "touch file.txt\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
```

But when i chek there is no file.txt. What's wrong?

Comment: Does that user have write access to that directory?

Comment: If I login manually with ssh and  execute a touch I'm able to create the file (I use mine user in the script)...so I think yes

Comment: Why don't you just `ssh numeutente@11.11.11.111 touch /var/www/localhost/htdocs/oss/file.txt` ? Login authentication can be managed with ssh keys

Comment: Great, I didn't think about this! Is the simplest solution, thanks!